# Percent of records with a single MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table `users` with columns `user_id, name, rate`. I want to get % positive rating. The formula for this is:

```
((all records with rating >= 3) / (total records)) * 100
```

This can be done by getting `total records` and `all records with rating >= 3` by two queries. But I want to get this done using only one query. How can I do this?

Comment: Show your current query as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(rate >= 3) * 100 / count(*)
from users
```